# jquery placeholder plugin 'jQuery is not defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem on [this page](http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/askEnvironmentLineapp/) getting a 'jQuery is not defined' error in Chrome and IE due to the jQuery placeholder script.

- jQuery is declared before the plugin script.
- There's no conflict with $ as far as I can tell

I'm really stumped on this one, any advice would be great. Cheers

Comment: are you sure the jquery script is actually being loaded?

Comment: Yeah, in all seriousness, there is no error on that page.

Comment: I get an error too. "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

Comment: just showed up for me too. Odd.

Comment: Really? In the Chrome web inspector I get 'jQuery is not defined' and IE7 and 9 I get 'jQuery is undefined'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/js/decc/ignitionSuite.js, which includes jQuery and jquery.placeholder dynamically in an iframe:

```
jqPath = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"
jqPlaceholderPath = "http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/js/decc/jquery.placeholder.min.js"
...
loadjscssfile(jqPath, "js");
...
loadjscssfile(jqPlaceholderPath, "js");
```

Since the scripts are included dynamically, the browser isn't required to block execution until the first one loads. That means its entirely possible for jquery.placeholder to load first before jQuery, and the error occurs.

Comment: Even though it's in a frame on a different domain? I wouldn't have thought that would have an effect on this. If it's a jQuery conflict how come it's only this and not the other plugins etc?

Comment: Oh I See. It was duplicate functionality in the frame, that's been scrapped now. Cheers

Comment: Didn't realize it was in an iframe. The plot thickens. Still investigating.

Comment: Well spotted. However, I don't think that scripts in the iframe should have any effect on other scripts. That should be fine. I think the problem is just that the jQuery and placeholder scripts are being loaded dynamically, so there is no guarantee that jQuery will load first.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it grc. Thanks for putting it together.

Comment: Thank you gents, I was fixated on the parent and forgot to check the iframe.